# Complex multi-dimensional list operations in Scala

Tags: scala, slice, collect

Given a list such as the following:

```
val dane = List(
    ("2011-01-04", -137.76),
    ("2011-01-04", 2376.45),
    ("2011-01-04", -1.70),
    ("2011-01-04", -1.70),
    ("2011-01-04", -1.00),
    // ... skip a few ...
    ("2011-12-22", -178.02),
    ("2011-12-29", 1800.82),
    ("2011-12-23", -83.97),
    ("2011-12-24", -200.00),
    ("2011-12-24", -30.55),
    ("2011-12-30", 728.00)
)
```

I'd like to sum the values (i.e. the second item of the inner lists) of a specific month (e.g. January, or `01`), using the following operations in the specified order:

1. `groupBy`
2. `slice`
3. `collect`
4. `sum`

Comment: Shouldn't this have the "homework" tag?  The best solution is not to use the exact operations in the order you specified; the only reason to use those that way would be as a homework exercise.

Comment: "use groupBy, slice , collect, sum in this order"...  Seems a bit restrictive; So who's setting homework in Scala nowadays?

Comment: @Rex beat me to the observation by about 1 second :)

Comment: What is/are "all monthy in whay"?  Are you trying to state that you need to list all values in January along with their sum?

Comment: If anyone can show me a good reason why `slice` is appropriate here, I'll eat my hat!

Comment: @Kevin - You can use `slice` instead of `substring` or `split`.  I don't know if that's a _good_ reason, but if so, I hope it's a tasty hat.

Comment: @Rex it's not a bad reason, maybe I'll just nibble at the lining a bit...

Comment: List trimmed and `homework` tag added

Comment: @Kevin Probably at least Odersky is teaching something about Scala, I guess.http://lampwww.epfl.ch/teaching/

Comment: I think that the reason someone would ask you to use those functions as a homework exercise would be to break you of the habit of doing things imperatively, possibly coupled with the fact that some things like pattern matching hadn't been taught yet.

Comment: Jesters, all of you! In all honesty, while homework questions are looked down upon, I think -5 is WAY underrated.

Comment: @Daniel I can vow that I personally didn't mark it down.  But when I spot these things I'll answer differently, giving subtle hints and trying to force the OP into actually doing a bit of private research and learning stuff.

Comment: @Kevin I agree with you. And this _is_ a bad question, in the sense that he is trying to get the answer instead of understand the methods available. Still, -5 was way too low.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm feeling contrary, so here's an answer that uses NONE of the prescribed methods: `groupBy`, `slice`, `collect` or `sum`

Avoiding `collect` was the hardest part, `condOpt`/`flatten` is just so much uglier...

```
val YMD = """(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)""".r

import PartialFunction._

(dane map {
  condOpt(_:(String,Double)){ case (YMD(_,"01",_), v) => v }  
}).flatten reduceLeft {_+_}
```

Comment: It worked in the REPL, unless I missed something in the copy/paste

Comment: @Debilski Nope, I didn't, seems to work fine for me.  What wrongness did you observe, exactly?

Comment: With `toMap` you lose all values for one day but the last one.

Comment: Hah! You're right... I should have spotted that, I've even *used* it on purpose in the past :)  +1 to you sir, answer updated accordingly.

Comment: I loved the use of `condOpt`. I have to add it to my repertoire.

Answer (score 8):

```
(for((YearMonthDay(_, 1, _), value)<-dane) yield value).sum

object YearMonthDay{
   def unapply(dateString:String):Option((Int, Int, Int)) ={ 
       //yes, there should really be some error checking in this extractor 
       //to return None for a bad date string
       val components = dateString.split("-")
       Some((components(0).toInt, components(1).toInt, components(2).toInt)) 
  }  

}
```

Comment: I think that's a handy unapply.

Comment: Yeah, it's the sort of thing that ends up in most of my projects, but just differently enough that it wouldn't make a good library

Comment: You spent too much time on that `YearMonthDay`. Try `val YearMonthDay = """(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)""".r` and use `"01"` instead of `1` in the map.

Comment: Nice, but you should have mapped `_.toInt` instead of applying it thrice.

Comment: should be `def unapply (dateString: String): Option [(Int, Int, Int) ] = {`, shouldn't it (Option with brackets, not parens).

Answer (score 5):

Now that Kevin has started the trend of contrary answers, here's one you should never use, but gosh, it works!  (And avoids every requested method, and will work on any month if you change the string, but it does require that the list be sorted by date.)

```
dane.scanLeft(("2011-01",0.0))((l,r) =>
  ( l._1,
    if ((l._1 zip r._1).forall(x => x._1==x._2)) l._2+r._2 else 0.0
  )
).dropWhile(_._2==0).takeWhile(_._2 != 0.0).reverse.head._2
```

Comment: Now that truly is a thing of beauty...  It certainly gets *my* upvote!

Comment: Haha, well, I would vote that a "-1, silly" if it were on /. (and if they had a silly tag).

Comment: Why `dropWhile`/`takeWhile` instead of simply `filter`?

Comment: @Daniel - Sure, filter would work also.  I had decided that I wanted the _first_ block if there was more than one, but there's no reason to choose that.  I also wasn't trying very hard to write an optimal solution!

Answer (score 4):

Break the problem up into smaller steps. Start with trying to split the list into one list for every month. You could use `groupBy` for this. Your first problem will probably be how to parse the date string. A general solution would be to use a custom date class and a regular expression; however a simpler ad-hoc solution of using an indexed substring (or `slice`) could be appropriate in this context.

A general tip would be to load the data into the Scala REPL and play around with it. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
val totals = new HashMap[Int, Double]
for (e <- dane) {
    val (date, value) = e
    val month = date.drop(5).take(2).toInt
    totals(month) = totals.getOrElse(month,0.0) + value
}
```

Another implementation using none of the suggested functions, and mutable collections and some bastard mix of procedural and functional style avoiding some useful functions :)

`totals` ends up as a map from month number to total.

Comment: You're getting dangerously close to a valid answer there :)

Comment: I abjectly seek your forgiveness :-P

Answer (score 3):

So, here's an idea:

- `groupBy`, because you need to group data from each month together
- `slice`, because you need to see which is the month of the date
- `collect`, because you need to `filter` by month and `map` to value
- `sum`, mmmm... I'm not sure where this one comes in. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I refuse to obfuscate `sum`.

```
import org.joda.time.DateMidnight
for (month <- 1 to 12) yield {
  dane map { case (d,v) => new DateMidnight(d).getMonthOfYear -> v }
  filter { case (m, v) => m == month }
  map (_._2)
  sum
}
```

Comment: +1 for use of jodatime, by far the nicest way to deal with dates.

Answer (score 0):

```
dane.groupBy (_._1.matches (".*-01-.*")).slice (0, 1).map (x => x._2).flatten .map (y => y._2).sum
```

I really should look up 'collect', which somehow should replace my map/flatten/map.

My result is: Double = 2234.29